# Big O and Order of growth

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Let’s say we have the following function:

$$T(n) = 33*n^2 + 55 - 12*n ∈ O(n^2)$$

Is it correct to say that $n^2$ is order of growth of $T(n)$?

And more commonly:

If $T(n) ∈ O(G(n))$

Is it correct to say that $G(n)$ is order of growth of $T(n)$?

And the last question.
Let’s say we have the following function without any Big O specification:

$$T(n) = 2*n^3 + 55 + 12*log n$$

Is it correct to say that $n^3$ is order of growth of $T(n)$?

Comment: Notice that $T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$, so it's really proper to refer to $T$ as having this growth. But $T(n) \in O(n^{100})$ as well, although we wouldn't say it has order of growth $n^{100}$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Correct me if I wrong. You are talking that it is technically correct (according to Big O definition) to say that if $T(n) = n$ then $T(n) ∈ O(n)$ and also $T(n) ∈ O(n^2)$ or even $T(n) ∈ O(n!)$ are true statements. Do you mean that?

Comment: @T.Bongers my question is a little bit different thing. Basically I'm trying to figure out if dominant term without a constant is exactly the same thing as function's growth rate.

Comment: Yes, if $T(n) = n$ then $T(n) \in O(n!)$ too. But it is false that $T(n) = \Theta(n!)$.

Comment: @T.Bongers yep, it comes from Big O definition. But in many articles I see phrase `order of growth` but can not find explicit definition of it. That What I'm looking for. For now I think that `order of growth` is just a function under the Big Theta parentheses and it could be also a function under the Big O parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

To anwser your question directly. When talking about Big-oh notation, you always take the biggest growth since big-oh is your upper limit so you are correct saying your function is n^3. Now when you say order of growth I assume you do not only mean upper limit, that's where you would use Big-Theta. When using big Theta you have to be able to set upper and lower limit to your function.